# How to ensure that values of a type may be manipulated only by its friends?

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a class template, `ptrs_and_refs_only<T>`, which only may be manipulated through pointers and references.  In other words, values of this type should be disallowed, except for things declared as `friend`s of the type.

Specifically, I'd like the compiler to issue an error if it encounters this type used as a function parameter:

```
void foo(ptrs_and_refs_only<int> x);  // error!
void bar(ptrs_and_refs_only<int> &x); // ok
void baz(ptrs_and_refs_only<int> *x); // ok
```

I know that I can make `ptrs_and_refs_only<T>`'s copy constructor `private`, but that doesn't seem to cause an error in this code:

```
template<typename T>
  class ptrs_and_refs_only
{
  private:
    ptrs_and_refs_only() {}
    ptrs_and_refs_only(const ptrs_and_refs_only &) {}
};

void foo(ptrs_and_refs_only<int> x) {}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Is this behavior possible?

Comment: That code doesn't cause an error, but I don't think you'll be able to call `foo` from `main` without causing a compiler error.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Agreed. It'd be nice if I could disallow ```foo```'s existence, though.

Comment: Well, a pure `virtual` function would disallow that `foo`, but.. you wouldn't be able to instantiate that class at all. :)

Comment: @JaredHoberock: You can't even disallow a function whose argument doesn't exist: `void foo(struct nonexistent &);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a skeleton, but I don't know if it'll be adaptable to what you need:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct notype
{
private:
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<notype<T>, T const &>::value,
                          void>::type dummy();
  notype(T &) { }
};

void foo(notype<int>)   { } // Error
void foo(notype<int> &) { }
void foo(notype<int> *) { }
```

You'd still need to find a way to make the class constructible for certain client classes.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: The private constructor prevents the class from being constructible from a `T const &`, so the `enable_if` fails and you cannot instantiate the template. Actually I don't know if it'll be useful like this, you might need some tweaking to get it to be actually constructible by *something*...

Comment: I understand that part, but why don't ```notype<int> &``` and ```notype<int> *``` also instantiate the template and cause the error?

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Pointers and references don't need complete types, and the template isn't instantiated for those declarations.